# Vue.js high cpu load whith no interaction

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I develop a website with vue component:
I wrote some vue components (based on bootstrap-vue) and I use them like regular html tags (but with v-bind attributes in order to pass values) into my html (so they are "in the DOM").
Everything is OK except than the browser (chrome) uses almost 100% of the cpu when the page is displayed (0% if I the page is still available but another tab is shown).

There is no user interaction (click, move pointer,...) and no code running (timers, asynchronous calls...) so (I think) there should be no javascript running and almost no CPU use.

Maybe there is a strange thing happening with the reactivity? Maybe a problem with the Vue main loop like an event (value change) triggering the same event (value change) triggering the same event (value change).....  and so on...

Any idea of the reason of the problem?
Is there any way to see if there is any javascript code running or any vue dedicated tool?

Comment: You can use the 'Performance' tab of the 'Developer Tools' and record your page for one second and then see what scripts are being called

Comment: In the performance tab I have only a graph of the frames/second and no script related data. What is the frames/sec, is Vue refreshing always the event even when there is no changes at all?

Comment: Look further in that tab. It should be in the lower pane in the Bottom-Up tab. You expand  "Function Call"

Comment: Thank you selim but I did look very carefully and there is no such "Function call"  ore related in Chrome and in Firefox. By "Developper Tools" do you mean the official vue plugin?